# Flask; IOS; iPhone; Mac (Safari) Download and Stream

Tags: python, ios, iphone, flask, safari

at fist sry for my english :D ^^

Information: i want to stream and Download Music
this is my code atm:

```
@app.route('/HTTP_Download/uploads/<filename>/<path:filepath>')
def download_file(filename, filepath):
    uploads_temp = os.path.join(filepath)
    uploads = "/%s" % uploads_temp
    return send_from_directory(uploads, filename, as_attachment=True)
```

this code runs by my Mac and other Computers only on my iPhone it strikes and it play the music directly in the Safari Browser.... but i want to download it... and store it on my phone
how i get this to work ?

and an other Problem about Stream.
is it Possible to Stream the Music like this over a template

```
render_template('Download_or_Stream.html', string_variable=mp3)
```

in the template: Download_or_Stream.html:
play the song over an Audio tag ?

i have no idea what i can do to run this code .....
i´m at the end :D

i hope anyone can help me out.

thx

Comment: Since there is not general storage on iOS safari does not offer saving of files. Any audio/video is just played.

Comment: but i can store other things .... like .nzb files ..... from here: http://nzbindex.com/

Comment: How about pass as_attachement=True to send_from_dorectory?

Comment: Hey, do you Mean that i'm Add the line pass to the code like do you do this ? So: ??
    return send_from_directory(uploads, filename,  pass as_attachment=True) ?